# How to transform every 2 rows into 1 row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE source_table (
    id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    category varchar(255) NULL,
    item int NULL,
    counter int NULL,
    length int NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dest_table(
    id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    from_item [int] NULL,
    to_item [int] NULL,
    length [int] NULL
);
```

The source table contains the following records:

```
INSERT INTO source_table SELECT 'A', 100, 1, 0
INSERT INTO source_table SELECT 'A', 101, 2, 10
INSERT INTO source_table SELECT 'A', 102, 3, 5
INSERT INTO source_table SELECT 'A', 103, 4, 7
INSERT INTO source_table SELECT 'A', 104, 5, 12
INSERT INTO source_table SELECT 'B', 101, 1, 0
INSERT INTO source_table SELECT 'B', 111, 2, 15
INSERT INTO source_table SELECT 'B', 114, 3, 6
INSERT INTO source_table SELECT 'B', 117, 4, 13
INSERT INTO source_table SELECT 'B', 119, 5, 8
```

The rows from the source table need to be transformed in such a way so that each record in the destination table would represent 2 rows from the source table.

What is the correct SQL syntax to transform the above rows as the following in the destination table?

```
100, 101, 10
101, 102, 5
102, 103, 7
103, 104, 12
101, 111, 15
111, 114, 6
114, 117, 13
117, 119, 8
```

Comment: How last row in the result set become `119, 5, 8`?? And how `117, 119, 8` missed?

Comment: @Ullas My bad. fixed the typo!

Comment: @MartinSmith MS SQL Server 2014

Comment: The order of what column denotes "next" and "previous"? `id`,  or `counter` or `item`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `SELF JOIN`.

**Query**

```
insert into dest_table([from_item], [to_item], [length])
select t.* from(
    select t1.[item] as col_1, t2.[item] as col_2, t2.[length]
    from source_table t1
    join source_table t2
    on t1.id = t2.id -1
)t
where t.[length] <> 0;
```

The result set looks like below.

```
+-----+-----+------+
|col_1|col_2|length|
+-----+-----+------+
| 100 | 101 | 10   |
| 101 | 102 | 5    |
| 102 | 103 | 7    |
| 103 | 104 | 12   |
| 101 | 111 | 15   |
| 111 | 114 | 6    |
| 114 | 117 | 13   |
| 117 | 119 | 8    |
+-----+-----+------+
```

**Edit**

If there is gap in the identity column. Then,

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select rn = row_number() over(
        order by id
    ), *
    from source_table
)
insert into dest_table([from_item], [to_item], [length])
select t.* from(
    select t1.[item] as col_1, t2.[item] as col_2, t2.[length]
    from cte t1
    join cte t2
    on t1.id = t2.id -1
)t
where t.[length] <> 0;
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't guarantee that identity has no gaps.

Comment: Then we can use a row_number option.

Comment: @msanz : It will take only the second length

Comment: @Ullas it will mix A & B (or whatever) categories in a single row if I'm not wrong

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `lag` window function:

```
select *
from   (select lag(item) over (partition by category order by item) as from_item,
               item as to_item,
               length
        from   source_table) base
where   from_item is not null
```

To insert this into the destination table is standard.

Comment: I imagine they might need `ORDER BY item` though the question isn't clear and there is three possibilities.

Comment: @MartinSmith, true, but eventually the sort order is not so relevant when the goal is only to insert the records in another table.

Comment: Not for sort order but in the definition of the lag. The from and to item column names suggests to me that this should be ordered by item rather than counter.

Comment: Indeed, it is not clear from the question. But your guess may be a better one. I update.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.item, b.item, b.length
FROM source_table as a
INNER JOIN source_table b
  ON a.id = b.id - 1
  AND a.category = b.category
```

Answer (score 0):

If that counter doesn't have gaps then you could do a self-join on that and the category.

For example:

```
DECLARE @source_table TABLE (
    id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    category varchar(1) NULL,
    item int NULL,
    [counter] int NULL,
    [length] int NULL
);

DECLARE @dest_table TABLE(
    id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    category varchar(1) NULL,
    from_item int NULL,
    to_item int NULL,
    [length] int NULL
);

INSERT INTO @source_table (category, item, [counter], [length]) values 
('A', 100, 1, 0),
('A', 101, 2, 10),
('A', 102, 3, 5),
('A', 103, 4, 7),
('A', 104, 5, 12),
('B', 101, 1, 0),
('B', 111, 2, 15),
('B', 114, 3, 6),
('B', 117, 4, 13),
('B', 119, 5, 8);

insert into @dest_table (category, from_item, to_item, [length])
select t1.category,  t1.item, t2.item, t2.[length]
from @source_table t1
join @source_table t2 
  on (t1.category = t2.category and t1.[counter]+1 = t2.[counter]);

select * from @dest_table;
```

If there would be gaps between Id or counter then row_number can be used to use the same method.
For example:

```
with SRC AS (
 select category, item, [length],
 row_number() over (partition by category order by id) as [counter] 
 from @source_table
)
insert into @dest_table (category, from_item, to_item, [length])
select t1.category,  t1.item, t2.item, t2.[length]
from SRC t1
join SRC t2
  on (t1.category = t2.category and t1.[counter]+1 = t2.[counter]);
```